# Rails: Column not populating after creating login/signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I made an app which worked fine until creating a login/signup page. Now, when an invoice is created, the Salesperson field stays blank. I've set it so that a new invoice cannot be created without first creating a login, but even then, when logged in as the user, the Salesperson field remains blank.

Here is the page code:

```
<th>Client</th>
<th>Salesperson</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th colspan="3"></th>


<tbody>
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
<tr>
<td><%= invoice.company %></td>
<td><%= invoice.salesperson %></td>
<td><%= invoice.amount %></td>
<td><%= invoice.date %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Display', invoice %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong to make a column not populate after creating the login page? I'm kinda of shooting in the dark as no changes were made to the invoice_controller or code. Just added in a user model and new.html.erb

My _form.html.erb partial extraction:

```
Company Salesperson
<address>
<%= f.input_field :salesperson, class: "form-control", id: "5" %>
<input class="form-control" id= "6"  placeholder="address line 1" />
<input class="form-control" id= "7"  placeholder="address line 2" />
<input class="form-control" id= "8"  placeholder="phone number" />
</address>
</div><!-- /.col -->
<div class="col-xs-4 invoice-col">
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

Here is the invoices controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :update, :create]
before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show]

# GET /invoices
# GET /invoices.json
def index
@search = Invoice.search(params[:q])
@invoices = @search.result
@invoices = Invoice.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 8)
end

def search
index
render :index
end

# GET /invoices/1
# GET /invoices/1.json
def show
end

# GET /invoices/new
def new
@invoice = Invoice.new
end

# POST /invoices
# POST /invoices.json
def create
@invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @invoice.save
    format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_invoice
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:amount, :company, :contragent, :currency, :date)
end
end
```

Comment: The `invoices#create` action on the `InvoicesController` is where these fields for each invoice would be set. We would need to see that, for starters. Second, my assumption would be that an `invoice` would `belong_to :salesperson`,  but without you sharing more relevant information, we don't know what the relationship between `invoice` and `salesperson` is.

Comment: Added Invoices Controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a helper such as `current_user` (or another helper that retrieves the currently logged in user):

**invoices_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)
  @invoice.salesperson = current_user
  ... your existing code ...
end
```

The create action will never assign a salesperson to an invoice unless you tell it to do so.

**Edit/Addition**

To make sure that future invoices MUST have an associated salesperson, you could add validation for it to your `invoice.rb` file:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :salesperson
  validates_prescence_of :salesperson
  ...
end
```

This way if somehow a form gets submitted for a new invoice without a salesperson logged in, the invoice will fail to save and you can display the error in the form.

Comment: I do have a sessions controller to retrieve current logged in user. Will try that now. Thanks!

This is what is showing as the Salesperson:
 #<User:0x007f360e0cb2c8>

Comment: Do I need to run an active record migration to associate?

    rails g migration AddSalespersonToInvoice salesperson:belongs_to

Comment: Yes, assuming you want an invoice to belong to a salesperson.

Comment: That looks like it fixed it, but now am running into this, so have to create the relation between the two databases as they do exist:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "salespeople" does not exist

Comment: Do you have a table specifically named `salespeople`? Or do you have a `users` table where a `salesperson` is a type of user?